# CSS background-image displaying incorrectly

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm trying to display a background image on a webpage, and it's showing the bottom two thirds of the image, followed by the top one third.

It's not a problem with the .jpg file; I tried a completely different image, identical symptoms.

I've boiled it down to a minimum test case, that just shows the image and nothing else. Browser is the latest version of Chrome on Windows 11.

If I replace `cover` with `contain` or `100% 100%`, the image disappears completely.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1920/1080');
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: are you looking for `min-height: 100vh;`? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: As @MHDAlaaAlhaj said, min-height:100vh; will solve your issue. check here https://jsfiddle.net/fu795x1m/

Comment: min-height:100vh is generally used for layouts that are meant to be fully visible within the viewport without scrolling, while min-height: 100% is used to ensure an element's height matches that of its parent container which must have a height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that your `html` does not have any defined `height` yet.

Add a height to the `body` and `html`, this will do the job.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: where the important part is the `html`, i.e. the parent of body

Comment: Yeah @mplungjan. Updated as well for more clarification.

Comment: It is not the body. It does not care. It is the 100% on its parent (HTML) that is the fix

Answer (score -1):

If you want to display background image with full height, full width and without repeat itself try to add this into body styles:

```css
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
```